# Trying to create a Teams Call Programmatically

Tags: .net-core, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am attempting to create a Microsoft Teams call programmatically, there are a few pre-requisites including registering your bot as [outlined in the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot). And my understanding of how to do this, is, by creating a Bot (which I have done) and then the bot is your middle man as sorts to the Microsoft Graph API.

I'm not sure if registering the bot on teams is necessary as I don't want the bot to participate in calls I need it purely for initiating 1:1 calls (myself to another user). [The documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) shows that the API for doing this is in beta.

After a bit of searching, I ended up following [this guide](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-c-sample-app/ba-p/144451#) which allowed me to set up a bot emulator in which I thought I could use to test API calls to but it seems this is purely for a chatbot as [image: seen here].

I also [found this thread](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/38534776-full-teams-client-api-including-call-control?page=1&per_page=20) which others are asking for the API to include basic things like

- Make a call
- Answer a call
- Redirect a call

etc..

I'm a little lost at the moment and the documentation from Microsoft isn't the best.
Once my bot is setup its unclear what needs to be done after that, does anybody have any experience in this area or has recreated this scenario that I'm trying to achieve? Any help at all would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Have you found the solutions to achieve this, I am trying the same thing but got stuck.

Comment: @FaisalGhaffar, Its been a long time since i left this but the work i was doing on it was put on hold due to the API not having the functions we needed anyways.

But to answer your question i did manage to get the bot calling me using the Microsoft 365 Directory but all work on it has been put on hold since then. 

Hopefully Microsoft does a big push soon to their API since Skype is reaching End Of Life, sorry i couldn't help anymore!

Answer (score 1):

To start using the Cloud Communications APIs, please view the [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-concept-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and the [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-get-started?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation. You can register a calling bot [here](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/articles/calls/register-calling-bot.html)

I hope this helps you get started. The calling API that you linked to has a v1.0 version as well - you can change the version on the top left-hand side